# Does less have an equivalent to vim's scrolloff?

Tags: less-unix

I have scrolloff set to 4 in vim.  This means that when I scroll up or down, there are 4 lines between the line I'm on and the bottom or top of the screen.

When I use less, usually to view a manpage, I use / to search for text.  If I'm looking for a command line option that does something and I search for the term 'something' usually 'something' shows up in the paragraph explaining a command, and the command line switch is a line or two above that, so I have to scroll up to see it.  Any ideas for how to make less act more like vim in this one case?

Comment: This is not really an answer, but you can hit `u` to back up one half-screen.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe you want the -j option.  It doesn't seem to have a bottom-or-top mode, but rather a bottom-mode or top-mode.  For instance:

```
less -j 4
```

Will always display your search term on the 4th line (from the top), whereas

```
less -j -4
```

Will always display your search term on the 4th line from the bottom.

And of course, you can use alias to make your preference the default, by adding this to your .bashrc, for instance:

```
alias less="less -j 4"
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you!  Now I just have to figure out why I didn't notice that on my second and third passes through man less...  BTW, instead of the alias, I used the $LESS env var.  Now man can pick up on the setting too.

Comment: Instead of alias, add `export LESS='-j 4'` to your shell startup file

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can make `less` do this by itself, but did you know you can use Vim in place of `less` as your pager?  There's a macro in the Vim installation macros/ directory called `less.vim`.  Copy it to your own `.vim/macros` directory to enable, then alias `less` in your `.bashrc` (or whatever your shell)

```
# example:
alias less='/usr/share/vim/7.x/macro/less.sh'
```

**EDIT** Unfortunately I just tried this myself and it ignores the `scrolloff` by default. You could modify the `less.sh` to `set scrolloff=3` at launch.